# How I can use more than 64 analog in arduino

Tags: programming

Hi dears
I want help I’m in begging in programming. I want use more than 64 analog pin for ldr photoresistor in single reading. Because I can’t   use digital pin 0-1.
Any methods I can use ,,,,
And How??

Comment: what are you trying to do? .... `Because I can’t use digital pin 0-1.` ... why do you say that? ... how would that give you 64 analog inputs?

Comment: Which Arduino? I don't know of any that have 64 analog inputs to start with. I agree with jstotola. What are you trying to achieve? This sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1):

You basically have 2 ways to do this:

- You can use multiplexer chips, which are capable of carrying analog signals. Then you can connect the multiplexers to an analog input and the inputs of the multiplexers to the LDRs. Each multiplexer gets controlled over multiple digital pins (depending on the exact chips; it may be good to find one with a serial interface like I2C) and connects the analog input with one of the LDRs. Which one depends on the control inputs.
- You can use external ADCs (Analog Digital Converters, like the one in the Arduino). These are normally controlled over a serial interface (like I2C) and give you multiple analog inputs at once. For example [this board from adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1085), which gives you 16 analog inputs and is controlled over only 2 lines (I2C, A4 and A5 on an Arduino Uno/Nano). This is probably a simpler way, though for a higher cost. If you want to to cheaper than the linked board, you may wanna use blank ADC chips instead of a breakout board.

Comment: Thanks dear you can help me more which the best and easier one,, and if you have an example for that.

Comment: Besr and easiest ist probably using the ADC board from adafruit. Are you willing to invest that much?

Answer (score 1):

I've just built a board that allows an Arduino to access 192 analog inputs - one at a time of course. More is possible. It uses 4067 16 x 1 analog mux chips. A single 8 bit port controls it.
Need a schematic?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My [page about multiplexers](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11976) gives some details about this approach.